# Shortcut evaluation instead of doing if(condition) expression;

Tags: c, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting

Recently, I've come across a piece of code like this (not the real one, but a shorter example based upon it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n;

  printf ("n? ");  
  scanf ("%d", &n);

  n%2 && printf ("N is odd\n");  /* <-- this is it */

  return 0;
}
```

In case anybody didn't get it, this code is the equivalent of:

```
int main()
{
  int n;

  printf ("n? ");  
  scanf ("%d", &n);

  if (n%2) 
    printf ("N is odd\n");

  return 0;
}
```

A disassembly of this code compiled with GCC 4.4.5-8 for x86-64 bits gives this for the part in which `n` is evaluated and `printf()` is conditionally called:

```
        andl    $1, %eax
        testb   %al, %al
        je      .L3
        movl    $.LC2, %eax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        testl   %eax, %eax
.L3:
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

Sounds like the code an `if` statement would generate. The "standard" way gives this:

```
        andl    $1, %eax
        testb   %al, %al
        je      .L2
        movl    $.LC2, %edi
        call    puts
.L2:
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

Slighly shorter, and a bit faster too, because the compiler can use `puts()` instead of `printf()`, as it has detected that `printf()` is being used to print a single string, and its return value is not used. The former example must evaluate the second expression after `&&` because the first one evaluated to true, so `printf()` had to be used to get a value to evaluate with.

So my point is: Could this shortcut evaluation trick be considered good coding? It works but... does it any better other than helping to win one-liner C contests? Judging by the example I've provided I'd say no, but may it exist an example that proves otherwise?

NOTE: while trying to compile the original code, the compiler even generated an ICE (MingW 2.95.2) with a text error saying something about "error while executing do_jump" or something like that.

Comment: This is really an opinion-based question, and thus might be closed. My subjective opinion is that the version using `&&` is less clear than just using an `if` to guard the `printf`. Anyway, this is why many companies have [coding conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) in place to prevent stuff like that.

Comment: Well, I'not really seeking for subjective opinions. My statement is that this trick seems not to be useful, but it might exist an example that proves that this trick performs better (using any metric, like speed or code size) than the equivalent if statement, and I'm asking if anybody knows such example(s).

Comment: Anything which obscures the intent of your code can not be considered good coding unless it has HUGE payback. (And in that case, it needs to be documented to death.)

And even if this was epsilon faster, most machines are fast enough and most programs are large enough these days that trying to micro-optimize the instructions is almost always the wrong choice unless you can *PROVE* that this is a critical path in your program.

Comment: @keshlam Could not agree more. If you need speed, switch to ASM. But before doing that, make bloody sure you really *do* need it :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This technique is not useful in general as it is contrary to generally-accepted convention and leads to unreadable code. (Note that this technique is acceptable in other languages, such as perl, where it is a commonly-used idiom.)

One place you may be forced to use this technique is in a function-like macro.

```
#define foo(x, y) (((x) % 2) && (y))
```

You cannot write the macro as

```
#define foo(x, y) if ((x) % 2) (y)
```

Because that would mess up things like

```
if (a) foo(x, y); else bar();
```

The usual workaround of

```
#define foo(x, y) do { if ((x) % 2) (y); } while (0)
```

does not work with the comma operator.

```
for (i = 0, foo(x, y); i < 10; i++) ...
```

That said, any such use of this idiom should be well-commented.

Comment: Of course if/else in C macros can also be handled via the ?: operator.