# Value return Variations in C

Tags: c, return, boolean

Can someone please help me understand why someone would use `return str[0] == 0 || true;` instead of just `true`.

Comment: Politely speaking: I cannot think of a good reason to do that kind of return sentence, and if that construction came from an instructor of you, or a book/webpage you are using, I would firmly consider to stop using them.

Comment: It came from a mentor in codewars. I told him that I got banned from stackover flow for using it. I am waiting for his response. Not sure why I got banned though. :(

Comment: You got banned from Stack Overflow for using it? That doesn't sound likely...

Comment: Your question has some resemblances to another one I wrote some years ago... 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/20930483/3011009

Comment: It doesnt make any sense @John Kugelman. I wrote it, 30 seconds later I cannot ask any questions. I now know that its bad code, but that should be a great answer from the community for new users of C like myself to tell us that. Not block me from asking questions.Thanks for your helps.

Comment: @AndrewB Either email the moderators or make a post on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: A way of identifying plagiarism?   At a quick glance, it looks like it 'does something important', and so it it likely to be copied if the work is plagged.

Comment: @AndrewB Post hoc....?  Maybe you were coincidentally banned for other reasons.  One bad question would not trigger a ban.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good explanation for it.

If the expression on the left of `||` had side effects--if it were a function call, for example--then there could be a reason. It'd still be bad style, but at least it wouldn't be useless.

For example, the function call here can't just be deleted:

```
return write(foo) || true;
```

But it would be much better to write it as:

```
write(foo);
return true;
```

But since `str[0] == 0` doesn't have any side effects it's useless at best, harmful at worst. It doesn't do anything except possibly crash if `str[0]` is an invalid pointer dereference.

If you apply the same transformation of moving the left-hand side to its own statement...

```
str[0] == 0;  // useless
return true;
```

...you can see that the first line is a no-op and ought to be deleted.

Comment: Yeah I am not at all interested in bad style. So now that I know that it is bad style, It is abandoned from my mind as useful code. I am learning very quickly that code can execute and follow the rules of the ISO and still be horrible code. 
Thanks for your response and help John, and all others that made an effort to help out. 
Cheers :)